# Rounding numbers - What's wrong here?

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.3, rounding

1. I have K a list of floats that **comes from some previous calculation**, such as:

   ```
   K = numpy.arange(0.01, 0.3, 0.01)
   K =  [0.01, .... 0.28999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999]
   ```
2. Now, lets round those numbers to the 2nd decimal:

   ```
   K_rounded_2  = [ round(kk, 2) for kk in K ]
   ```

   Gives:

   ```
   >>> K_rounded_2
   [0.01, 0.02, 0.029999999999999999, 0.040000000000000001, 0.050000000000000003, 0.059999999999999998, 0.070000000000000007, 0.080000000000000002, 0.089999999999999997, 0.10000000000000001, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14000000000000001, 0.14999999999999999, 0.16, 0.17000000000000001, 0.17999999999999999, 0.19, 0.20000000000000001, 0.20999999999999999, 0.22, 0.23000000000000001, 0.23999999999999999, 0.25, 0.26000000000000001, 0.27000000000000002, 0.28000000000000003, 0.28999999999999998, 0.29999999999999999]
   ```

Now,  if i was **to manually input K as a list,** simply writing each element:

```
K = [ enter value 1, enter value 2, ...]
```

and then do:

```
K_rounded_2  = [ round(kk, 2) for kk in K ]
```

then the result is as expected:

```
>>> K_rounded_2
[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3]
```

So there is a different treatment between the list that is provided by some calculation and the one that is simply input ? Why ?

Comment: It's not possible to reproduce this without seeing your previous calculations.  Can you edit your question to include these?  Include the actual rounding code as well.

Comment: @Wolf: I don't think it matters *how* those values were obtained. I'm guessing that the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This difference is due to the fact that in the first case the result contains `np.float64`s while when you enter the numbers directly you are using python's built-in `float` *which has a smarter string representation*:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(0.01, 0.3, 0.01)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([ 0.01,  0.02,  0.03,  0.04,  0.05,  0.06,  0.07,  0.08,  0.09,
        0.1 ,  0.11,  0.12,  0.13,  0.14,  0.15,  0.16,  0.17,  0.18,
        0.19,  0.2 ,  0.21,  0.22,  0.23,  0.24,  0.25,  0.26,  0.27,
        0.28,  0.29])

In [4]: [round(elem, 2) for elem in a]
Out[4]: 
[0.01,
 0.02,
 0.029999999999999999,
 0.040000000000000001,
 0.050000000000000003,
 0.059999999999999998,
 0.070000000000000007,
 0.080000000000000002,
 0.089999999999999997,
 0.10000000000000001,
 0.11,
 0.12,
 0.13,
 0.14000000000000001,
 0.14999999999999999,
 0.16,
 0.17000000000000001,
 0.17999999999999999,
 0.19,
 0.20000000000000001,
 0.20999999999999999,
 0.22,
 0.23000000000000001,
 0.23999999999999999,
 0.25,
 0.26000000000000001,
 0.27000000000000002,
 0.28000000000000003,
 0.28999999999999998]

In [5]: b = [0.01,
   ...:  0.02,
   ...:  0.029999999999999999,
   ...:  0.040000000000000001,
   ...:  0.050000000000000003,
   ...:  0.059999999999999998,
   ...:  0.070000000000000007,
   ...:  0.080000000000000002,
   ...:  0.089999999999999997,
   ...:  0.10000000000000001,
   ...:  0.11,
   ...:  0.12,
   ...:  0.13,
   ...:  0.14000000000000001,
   ...:  0.14999999999999999,
   ...:  0.16,
   ...:  0.17000000000000001,
   ...:  0.17999999999999999,
   ...:  0.19,
   ...:  0.20000000000000001,
   ...:  0.20999999999999999,
   ...:  0.22,
   ...:  0.23000000000000001,
   ...:  0.23999999999999999,
   ...:  0.25,
   ...:  0.26000000000000001,
   ...:  0.27000000000000002,
   ...:  0.28000000000000003,
   ...:  0.28999999999999998]

In [6]: [round(elem, 2) for elem in b]
Out[6]: 
[0.01,
 0.02,
 0.03,
 0.04,
 0.05,
 0.06,
 0.07,
 0.08,
 0.09,
 0.1,
 0.11,
 0.12,
 0.13,
 0.14,
 0.15,
 0.16,
 0.17,
 0.18,
 0.19,
 0.2,
 0.21,
 0.22,
 0.23,
 0.24,
 0.25,
 0.26,
 0.27,
 0.28,
 0.29]
```

Now if we check the types of the elements of these lists:

```
In [10]: rounded_a = [round(elem, 2) for elem in a]
    ...: rounded_b = [round(elem, 2) for elem in b]
    ...: 

In [11]: type(rounded_a[0]), type(rounded_b[0])
Out[11]: (numpy.float64, builtins.float)
```

However *the numbers represented are the same!*

```
In [12]: rounded_a[0] == rounded_b[0]
Out[12]: True
In [13]: rounded_a[-1] == rounded_b[-1]
Out[13]: True
```

The *printed* value is different because python built-in floats are smarter and display the shorter literal that would represent the given floating-point number
(see python's 3.1 [What's new](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html) document and associated [issue1580](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580)):

```
In [15]: 0.28999999999999998
Out[15]: 0.29
```

Numpy does do this and instead just outputs the "raw/actual floating-point number represented". But notice that *the result is the same*, it is only *displayed* differently, although in an equivalent way.